# How to find documents with a combination of two fields in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection which stores documents like this

```js
{
  // Other fields
  'date':'07/01/2021',
  'time':'09:21:10'
}
```

and I want to find documents greater than a specific date

```py
yesterdays_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24))

docs = db.collection.find({'date': {'$gte': yesterdays_date}}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally refactor your collection to store the date/times as a BSON date object; then your query would work.

Answer (score 0):

you stored data like string :

```
{
    // Other fields
   'date':'07/01/2021', // => type = string 
   'time':'09:21:10' //  => type = string 
}


yesterdays_date // => returns datetime
```

if u wanna compare u should compare with datetime , not string with datetime

other problem is :
you should compare date with date ( not datetime format)